# creating multiple clipping paths in HTML5 canvas using loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I cannot create multiple clipping paths in canvas. With this code, if i=1, I get the clipping path working correctly. For i>1, I only see clipping if the paths are overlapping. Otherwise, nothing is drawn to the canvas.

```
    function draw() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            var x = 25 + 25 * i; // x coordinate
            var y = 75; // y coordinate
            var radius = 20; // Arc radius
            var startAngle = 0; // Starting point on circle
            var endAngle = Math.PI * 2; // End point on circle
            var anticlockwise = true; // clockwise or anticlockwise

            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);

            ctx.clip();

        }

       ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 150);

    }
```

If it is not possible to have multiple clipping masks on the canvas, is there another compositing method that is the same as clipping mask?

Comment: Move the `ctx.clip()` outside the loop. And the `ctx.beginPath` to before the loop

Comment: Oh, you are right. That worked. Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: Ill make it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to have multiple shapes in your clip area you need to define all the shapes then apply the clip. If you set the clip after adding each shape you end up clipping only inside the previous clip.

So move `ctx.clip()` to after the for loop, it need only be called once, and move the `ctx.beginPath()` to before the loop.

Comment: Yep, upvote...and just adding that `context.clip` is cumulative so multiple clips will create a final clipping area that is the intersection of all clips. That's why `.clip` inside the loop might eventually reduce the clipping area to nothing (and therefore nothing is drawn).